# How prove this diophantine equation $x^2+y^2+z^3=n$ always have integer solution

Tags: number-theory

> show that: For any postive ineteger $n$,then the equation 
>   $$n=x^2+y^2+z^3$$
>   always have integer solution

My idea: such as $n=1$,then we have
$$1=0^2+0^2+1^3$$
$$2=0^2+1^2+1^3$$
$$3=1^2+1^2+1^3$$
$$4=2^2+0^2+0^3$$
$$5=1^2+2^2+0^3$$
$$6=1^2+2^2+1^3$$
$$7=2^2+2^2+(-1)^3$$
$$8=0^2+0^2+2^3$$
$$9=1^2+0^2+2^3$$
$$10=1^2+1^2+2^3$$
$\cdots\cdots\cdots$

But for  general $n$, How prove it?

Comment: Too Broad is a particular wrong reason to close this. Is somebody really being a bad actor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s a proof using a solution I found [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=850013&sid=5b6ac716220d0c085566503775b5338c#p850013).

Write $n$ in the form $8^m\cdot s$, for an integer $m\ge0$ and with $s$ not divisible by $8$. This can always be done. Note that an integer $s$ that is not a multiple of $8$ can be written in one of the following three forms: $2k+1$ (if $s$ is odd), $4k+2$ (if $s$ is even, but not a multiple of $4$), or $8k+4$ (if $s$ is even and a multiple of $4$).

First, find an expression for $s$ in the form $a^2+b^2+c^3$ as follows. (I haven’t checked these details.)

If $s=2k+1$, let $a=k^2-k-1$, $b=k^3-3k^2+k$, and $c=-k^2+2k$.

If $s=4k+2$, let $a=2k^3-2k^2-k$, $b=2k^3-4k^2-k+1$, and $c=-2k^2+2k+1$

If $s=8k+4$, let $a=k^2-2k-1$, $b=k^3+k+2$, and $c=-k^2-1$

Now observe that if $s$ is the sum of two squares and a cube, so is $8s$, because $8(a^2+b^2+c^3)=(2a+2b)^2+(2a-2b)^2+(2c)^3$. Inductively, if $s$ is the sum of two squares and a cube, then so is $8^ms$ for any nonnegative integer $m$.

We have already shown that $s$ is the sum of two squares and a cube, so $n=8^ms$ is as well, completing the proof.

Comment: The case $s = 8k+4$ is not correct. The expression $a^2 + b^2 + c^3$ comes out to $4-4k^4$.

Comment: $b = k^3+k+2$. I've taken the liberty to edit your answer.

Comment: @RghtHndSd: Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

My friend put this as an MAA Monthly problem, years ago. The comparison is that [there are infinitely many numbers that have no expression as](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Experimental_1995.pdf) $x^2 + y^2 + z^9.$ This simple result defeated an existing conjecture; we sent it early to Robert C. Vaughan, so it made it into the second edition of his book *The Hardy-Littlewood Method*. It is likely that every number can be written as $x^2 + y^2 + z^5,$ but not certain.

See http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Elkies_Kap.pdf

and related items at http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/inhom.html

Comment: Nice indentity,thank you!