# Prove that every integer is a sum of two squares and a cube of integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that every integer is a sum of two squares and a cube of integer.

Probably the only connected result I know, is the Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares. But I don't know how to prove that in other cases (for numbers not being of the form $x^2+y^2=x^2+y^2+0^3$) one can choose such two squares that the remainder will be a cube.

Comment: The example of $7$ shows that you need to allow that the cube may be negative

Comment: I'm very sorry - the cube of an integer, edited.

Comment: See Elkies & Kaplansky, Problem 10426, Amer Math Monthly 102 (1995) 70.

Comment: See also http://pen.problem-solving.be/viewtopic.php?t=520

Comment: See also https://cms.math.ca/crux/v27/n7/CRUXv27n7.pdf (search for Elkies).

Comment: also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039106/how-prove-this-diophantine-equation-x2y2z3-n-always-have-integer-solution

Comment: Thanks. By the way, 3 links given by Will Jagy in his answer, are dead now. The active link to Elkies & Kaplansky problem is cms.math.ca/crux/v27/n7/CRUXv27n7.pdf given above by  Gerry Myerson.

Answer (score 0):

You may exploit the fact that:
$$ (4t^2+1)^3-(8t^3+3t)^2 = 1+3t^2 $$
and similar parametric identities to prove that $x^2+y^2+z^3$ represents every integer represented by some binary quadratic forms, hence every integer.